# Powershell: Remote exe Installation

Tags: windows, powershell, exe, invoke-command

I'm having problems with my script that is designed to install an executable remotely. All of the preliminary actions of my script work just fine. I grab the host names of about a dozen computers from a text file. I use PSExec to Enable-PSRemoting. Then the installer is copied down to a temp directory on the remote computer. Everything works great, except for the important part. I just can't get it to install.

I've tried the following:

```
 Invoke-Command -ComputerName remoteComp -ScriptBlock {C:\temp\installer.exe} -ArgumentList /SILENT
 Invoke-Command -ComputerName remoteComp {Start-Process C:\temp\installer.exe -ArgumentList /SILENT -Wait}
```

I've tried using New-PSSession like this:

```
 $s = New-PSSession -ComputerName remoteComp
 Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {C:\temp\installer.exe} -ArgumentList /SILENT
```

None send any sort of error, they just do nothing. Commands that have -Wait just hang forever. If I put a -Sleep, it just waits the requested seconds and then finishes, accomplishing nothing. I don't know if this matters, but when I run the executable on the local computer with the /SILENT switch, it doesn't request any prompts but it does open an explorer window.

I tried to use PSExec.exe, but I get a similar result. It just hangs forever without any error. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I have tried this on various installers, some work depending on UAC level. I ended up writing something to execute the creation of a scheduled task on a target machine that runs a batch file with all my silent install commands. `SCHTASKS`

Comment: in the scriptblock examples you have your are not passing the parameter to your exe. `-ScriptBlock {C:\temp\installer.exe $args[0]} -ArgumentList /SILENT` although there might be more going on. That would explain why it goes on forever since it cannot interact with any user. There is free software that can handle this sort of thing like PDQ Deploy instead of trying to make your own fyi.

Comment: The explorer window appearing might be causing the install process not to end, which would explain why when you use `-Wait` it doesn't ever end. You can test this on a local computer... open Task Manager and run the installer with silent switch, quickly find the `installer.exe` process in Task Manager. When the installer opens an explorer window appears does the `installer.exe` process disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the argument list inside ... if the exe supports it.

ex:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { c:\temp\yourexe.exe /verysilent /norestart /log="c:\install.log"}
```

Please try.

Comment: Unfortunately, this exe doesn't support /verysilent

Comment: try /silent along with the exe if /verysilent is not supported

Answer (score 3):

After fighting with this thing a little more, I was able to successfully install the exe by creating a batch file and then using

```
 Invoke-Command -ComputerName remoteComp -ScriptBlock {C:\temp\installer.bat}
```

All that's in the batch file is

```
 installer.exe /SILENT
```

Another way that worked for me was mentioned by ssaviers, I could use schtasks.exe to schedule a one time task.

Comment: I was getting ignored too... until I found this :-) needs marking as the correct answer!